# In JS, how do I access a given property path of any given object?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

To make things more clear, here's an example. I tried to strip everything down to the bone and only keep the relevant details. Here's a dummy class `Person` with some properties and subproperties:

```
class Person {
  height = 100;
  hat = {size: 4};
}
```

Now, I have some other class whose purpose is to modify some (sub)*property of `Person`:

```
class PersonModifier {
  constructor(propertyPath, value) {
    this.propertyPath = propertyPath; // this is the part I'm a bit lost on
    this.value = value; // a numeric value just to demonstrate how this class would work
  }

  actUpon(person) { // modifies a quantitative attribute of Person by a given amount
    person.(this.propertyPath) += value;
  }
}
```

I'm aware the sole line of code inside the `actUpon` method doesn't work syntactically, I hope I got the point across as to what I'm trying to do. I guess it's similar to `Person.prototype.whatever` but I'd like to use it for attributes and not for methods.

Here's an example of instance of the above class, whose purpose is to decrease one's hat size by 2:

```
let hatShrinker = new PersonModifier(.hat.size, -2);
```

Again, that obviously doesn't work syntactically, so here's my question:

How do I store and use a property path (of arbitrary depth), such that I can access and write such properties of any object? Consider that I know what classes the object belongs to beforehand (in this example, `Person`).

**Note:** *any solution not involving strings would be preferred, as strings are not affected by some important IDE features like refactoring and suggestions based on dynamic type*

Comment: I think using strings somehow is the only good way to do this, fundamentally - either through an array of strings, or through a single string dot-separated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do think you're probably stuck with strings of some sort. In this example, I use an array of strings to dive down the object path and mutate the final key of the final object.

```js
class PersonModifier {
  constructor(propertyPath, value) {
    this.propertyPath = propertyPath;
    this.value = value;
  }

  actUpon(person) {
    const path = [...this.propertyPath];
    const prop = path.pop();
    const obj = path.reduce((acc, el) => {
      return acc[el];
    }, person);
    obj[prop] += this.value;
  }
}

const hatShrinker = new PersonModifier(["hat", "size"], -2);

const person = {
  hat: {
    size: 4
  }
};

hatShrinker.actUpon(person);

console.log(person);
```